# Tried to Add Post Method in Play but It shows error

Tags: java, java-8, playframework, routes

here is my post method

```
 public Result  addMatch(Http.Request request){
        JsonNode jsonNode = request.body().asJson();
        if (jsonNode == null){
            return badRequest("Error");
        }
        //Optional<Match> match = request.body().parseJson(Match.class);
        Match match = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, Match.class);
        LeagueManager leagueManager = new PremierLeagueManager();
        leagueManager.addPlayedMatch(match);
        JsonNode jsonObject = Json.toJson(match);
        return created(ApplicationUtil.createResponse(jsonObject,true));
    }
```

here is my router

```
POST     /AddMatch     controllers.MatchController.addMatch(request: Request)
```

This is the error that displaying
error 2020-12-27 11:21:50 WARN  play.filters.CSRF  [CSRF] Check failed because application/json for request /addMatch
can someone solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF filter expects a token to be send along the request. Looking at the error, the CSRF token is not present. You have 3 options :

1. Send the proper CSRF token
2. Disable CSRF per endpoint by adding +nocsrf above the entry in the routes file
3. Disable CSRF all together by adding

```
play.filters {
  disabled += play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
}
```

to application.conf